# How to unlock all difficulty levels?

Tags: pc, max-payne-2

Max Payne 2 locks all difficulty levels ("Dead Man Walking" is an alternative game mode")  by default, forcing players to complete the game multiple times. Additionally, "detective" is an adaptive difficulty level [according to the game's Wikia page](http://maxpayne.wikia.com/wiki/Max_Payne_2:_The_Fall_of_Max_Payne) and experienced players may want to skip over the setting entirely.

[image: difficulty selection]

In the original Max Payne, it was possible to unlock all difficulty levels by editing registry ([source](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/913964-max-payne/cheats), under "instantly unlock all gameplay modes"). Max Payne 2 even follows the same folder structure (`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Remedy Entertainment\Max Payne 2\Game Level`), but I'm unsure what values to set.

[image: registry editor]

Comment: It took literally five seconds of googling to find the answer to this.  While prior research is not required to ask here, it most definitely is expected.

Comment: @Frank: Post an answer then and I will accept it if your method works. I didn't find a solution for MP2 aside from completing the game 2-3 times. I however happened to solve the issue while writing this question and posted if someone wants to collect reputation.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Frank some self research is a nice thing to do. But since it has been unanswered [here](https://www.gamespot.com/max-payne-2-the-fall-of-max-payne/cheats/) it is.

> Go to Start Menu->Run and type in ''regedit''. Press Enter. In the
> directory tree on the left, Go to
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER->Software->RemedyEntertainment->Max Payne 2.
>
> Click on the ''Game Level'' folder, and
> some items will appear on the right side of the screen.
>
> Right-Click
> and select New->DWORD Value
>
> Double-Click on the entry you just made and set the value to 1. Rename
> the entries to the following:
>
> - LevelSelector - Unlocks ''Level Select'' mode
> - timedmode - Unlocks> ''New York Minute'' and ''Dead Man Walking'' modes
> - nightmare - Unlocks
>   ''Hard-Broiled'' mode
> - hell - Unlocks ''Dead On Arrival'' mode

EDIT: Instead of renaming the entries you can create a new (DWORD 32-bit) entry that way not destroying any of the original values.

Comment: Gamespot's community guide is a bit incoherent. Instead of "renaming", you create a new (DWORD 32-bit) entry for each difficulty mode. I certainly wouldn't touch the existing values.

Comment: Added the additional info, for editing over replacing

Comment: May I rewrite the answer? I will leave the Gamespot link as a source, but remove quoted text, replacing with a simple solution. For instance, adding paths which can be pasted into the registry editor for registry entries. While the guide points to the right solution, it is poorly worded to the point of being false.

Comment: You can suggest an edit, I do think you should leave the original just expand upon it